# Will I get rewarded if I try my best to study good in school?

Tags: allah, science, blessings-of-allah

I was wondering, if it is true that God Almighty does not like the lazy people, those who don't study at school?
  And is that true that if God Almighty see you not only at Muslims also at non-Muslims  are trying hard and being ambitious on studying math and physics and etc. then He'll help you even if you haven't ask Him, and even to know that He is helping you in the way so that the person will succeed and will also God Almighty prepare for that person a bright, wonderful with highest salary and to have also easy life and he can also be able to build a device or a machine or to do any amazing things in future as a reward from God?

And the last thing is, if He'll be very happy if He see someone who tries to study well in school?

Just to know

Comment: I give some advice for writing titles to questions here: [Advice for writing question titles on Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1837/17163).  Please consider [edit]ing the title of this question and your other questions to indicate what the question actually is.

Comment: You mean to edit my question title?Then what title shall I put?

Comment: The idea is to pinpoint the exact question you want to ask, and put that as the title.  Then everyone knows precisely what the question is about.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Is ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

God loves believers and the doers of good and those who fear him and those who rely on him and those who act justly, and He dislikes infidels and wrongdoers and traitors and the arrogant people . God dislikes corruption.

Being lazy in school is not that critical in this context . Of course , you can study hard with the intention of making your life better and make you parents happy , then it is a good deed. you can be lazy on purpose , to harm yourself or make your parents sad , on purpose , then it is not a good deed . You cannot be sure what God will give you in the future. You do your best in learning and working , and make Duaa to Allah always , as Duaa itself is an act of worshipping.

May Allah reward you .